XQueryKeymap - how to calculate an index for the key
I have an array with some key symbols, for example:
KeySym keySymbols[] = {XK_Escape, XK_Return, XK_A};

I would like to check if those keys are pressed using XQueryKeymap. I have found an answer here, but it's not clear for me how the index for accessing the keys_return array is calculated. Could you please explain it ? What is the meaning of the numbers 3,1 and 7 used for shifting bits ?

KeyCode XKeysymToKeycode(display, keysym)
